# Attribute name "from" associated with an element type "Hello" must be followed by the ' = ' character. - Apache Camel

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I'm developing **Spring + Apache Camel** example for scheduling. I created `applicationContext.xml` and added `<camelContext>` details for scheduling, But when I simply run my main method. I see following error. Not sure whats wrong in XML file.

Error for reference:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 25; Attribute name "from" associated with an element type "Hello" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.camel.scheduler.CamelTimerSimpleExampleUsingSpring.main(CamelTimerSimpleExampleUsingSpring.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 25; Attribute name "from" associated with an element type "Hello" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:418)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://simpleTimer?period=1000" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>
                 <Hello from timer at $ header.firedTime } />
                </simple>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

**CamelTimerSimpleExampleUsingSpring.java**

```
public class CamelTimerSimpleExampleUsingSpring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        CamelContext camelContext = null;
        try {
            camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);

            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            try {
                camelContext.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <!-- General Properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Apache Camel -->
        <apache.camel.version>2.17.3</apache.camel.version>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>

        <!-- Logging Framework -->
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.21</jcl-over-slf4j.version>

        <!-- Junit Framework -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- Camel core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel stream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your applicationContext like shown below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://simpleTimer?period=1000" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thnx, bit I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver too

Answer (score 0):

In order to run this code, you need to make the following changes in pom.xml. You should be using the spring dependencies first, you follow your pom.xml then application will get the spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE and it will give Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver`. Please use below suggested order and

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel stream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- camel JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> <version>${logback.version}</version> 
            </dependency> -->

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and use corrected

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://simpleTimer?period=1000" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

It looks like Alexey Yakunin suggested correct answer too. But I see that

```
camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);
```

method is deprecated, Alexey, do you know what should be use instead ?